# Gurobi Reducing Binary Variable Makes Solve Time Longer

Tags: optimization, gurobi, mixed-integer-programming

I'm solving MILPS with one binary variable. I have written an algorithm to reduce the binary variables. It works and gives the same solution. The unreduced binary variables is 33 variables. The reduced one is 19 variables. I found that running with 33 binary variables takes about 11 seconds while the reduced one takes about 12.5-13 seconds.

I'm wondering how this is possible since the expectation was that reducing the binary variable would makes things much faster as less options have to be explored.

What would be the reason for this to be the other way around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that Gurobi automatically finds a similar reduction for the original model, and the different runtimes are just due to performance variability. You should check with multiple random seeds to get a feeling for the performance variability.

It is hard to say more with such limited information on the model.

Comment: Yes thank you this helped it is now 5 seconds faster with reduction on average. Interesting that gurobi does not use random seed itself but i suppose this is done to have reproducable results even when the seed is not set.

Comment: Gurobi does always use a random seed - you just have the option to change it to some other value. The seed is used to generate random numbers throughout the solving process. It is impossible to predict a "good" seed for a given instance.

Comment: Gurobi does not use a "random" seed because it is designed to be deterministic and give the same answer with the same inputs. However, as @mattmilten noted, you can change the seed value yourself. This is the danger when interpreting performance from a single instance.

Comment: Exactly, Greg, thanks! I was thinking of "random seed" in the sense of "seed to generate random numbers" not that the seed value itself was chosen randomly. That was not very clear.